Implement the IntoIter and Iterator trait for VecData<T>(Rc<RefCell<Rc<Vec<T>>>>)
I have a relatively complex data structure (for reasons I don't want to go into here).
It is defined as
pub struct VecData<T>(Rc<RefCell<Rc<Vec<T>>>>);

What I am looking for is a way to implement the IntoIter and Iterator traits for this struct. To be precise, I want to be able to iterate over the elements of type &T without cloning the inner Vec<T>.

What's the issue you're running into when trying to create the iterator?

You cannot do that, but you can come close, by yielding Ref<T> instead:
use std::cell::{Ref, RefCell};
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct VecData<T>(Rc<RefCell<Rc<Vec<T>>>>);

impl<T> VecData<T> {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<'_, T> {
        Iter {
            data: self.0.borrow(),
            index: 0,
        }
    }
}

pub struct Iter<'a, T> {
    data: Ref<'a, Rc<Vec<T>>>,
    index: usize,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = Ref<'a, T>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index >= self.data.len() {
            return None;
        }

        let item = Ref::map(Ref::clone(&self.data), |data| &data[self.index]);
        self.index += 1;
        Some(item)
    }
}

The reasoning you cannot do that is as follows: imagine you could do that, then you could create the iterator, extract the first item out of it then drop the iterator. Now you have a &T pointing to inside the Rc<Vec>, and no bookkeeping to inform the RefCell it is borrowed. Now you replace the inner Rc by borrow_mut()ing the RefCell. You got a dangling reference! Surely this has to be disallowed.

Thanks a lot! Can you maybe explain why one cannot do that? (Just out of curiosity, your solution perfectly does solve my problem.

@Sebastian Edited to explain.

Thanks! What I don't understand though is the following: As long as the Iter that owns the Ref<'_, Rc<Vec<T>> lives, I cannot have a dangling reference I think, because this will ensure that the RefCell is not dropped. So why can the compiler not ensure that the Iter outlives the &Ts that are yielded from it?

And also can you maybe add how to implement the IntoIter for this?

@Sebastian Just implement IntoIterator for &'a VecData<T> calling iter().

Thanks! But just to follow up on the question above: Why is it not possible to avoid the dangling reference in your example by ensuring that the lifetime of the Iterator is at least as long as the lifetimes of the yielded &T?

Nevermind, I get it now: This is because of the signature of the next(&mut self) method, which means that the yielded elements need to be able to outlive the Iterator itself, as their lifetime cannot be related to the lifetime of Iterator, only of &mut self

I just realized that implementing IntoIterator for &'a VecData<T> does not solve my problem. I need to implement it for VecData<T>

@Sebastian That's precisely it. There is a lot of value in being able to create an iterator with a different contract, google "lending iterator" for details. But that kind of iterator would not support many iterator methods, such as collect(), so it's unclear whether it's possible to extend Iterator to support that use case. (And even writing a purely lending iterator trait has proven trickier than it appears.)

Actually I think I did not express myself properly @ChayimFriedman. I don't need the IntoIter trait, but I want the method into_iter(self) that takes ownership of the VecData. But I suspect that this is impossible again due to the same reason as to why it is impossible to yield &T?

@Sebastian In that case the first step would be to ask a question with what you actually want to do, because right now you cornered yourself into Y of a XY-problem, but to add a proper answer we need to know X.

Yes, I tried to write down my whole problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78468750/how-to-get-an-iterator-for-two-nested-rcs-and-refcells. Still, the question here already improved my understanding quite a bit, so it was not futile :)
