How to get an Iterator for two nested Rcs and RefCells
I have a very complicated data-structure and I am trying to get an Iterator over its internal elements. The top-level structure is a Reppresentation of a vector. However, different internal RepTypes (an enum) are possible (e.g. an Iterator or an allocated vector). I need the first RefCell in order to change the internal representation of a vector in-place. E.g. in some cases I wan't to .collect() an iterator into an allocated vector.
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct Rep<T>(RefCell<RepType<T>>);

The RepType might look as follows, but for the question below I really only care about the Allocated vector for now.
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum RepType<T> {
    Allocated(VecData<T>),
    // more will come, e.g. an Iterator
}

Unfortunately, the VecData is again a very complex data structure:
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct VecData<T>(Rc<RefCell<Rc<Vec<T>>>>);

I need this data structure to be able to get mutable views and lazy copies of the internal data (in order to avoid unnecessary copying as much as possible).
impl<T> VecData<T> {
    /// Create a (lazy) copy of the data.
    pub fn lazy_copy(&self) -> Self {
        Self::new(Rc::new(RefCell::new(self.0.borrow().clone())))
    }

    // Create a mutable view on the data.
    pub fn mutable_view(&self) -> Self {
        Self::new(Rc::clone(&self.0))
    }
}

For more information on this, see this question and the discussion in the comments, but these aspects is not essential to my question here, I just wanted to give some justification for the datastructure complexity.
I now want to be able to iterate over the elements of the internal VecData that is wrapped by the RepType without cloning the internal Vec<T>.
I have already asked a related question and know how to implement iter() for VecData, see here. While this is helpful, I noticed that it does not quite solve my problem.
What I am looking for here, is an implementation of Rep::iter(), i.e. something like:
impl Rep<T> {
  fn iter(&self) -> RepIter {
    // ???
  }
}

struct RepIter {
  // ???
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for RepIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = Ref<'a, T>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
       // ???
    }
}

What seems to make this quite tricky is that there are now two nested RefCells and two nested Rcs, so I really don't know how to approach this or whether it is even possible to implement this. Any help is appreciated!
Edit: I believe while .into_iter(self) might be impossible, implementing .iter(&self) should be possible, as the iterator then does not yield references into itself. (In the original question I was asking for an .into_iter(self) method instead of the .iter(&self) method.)

There are no nested RefCells. You might want to ask about creating iter for Rep instead.

argh, yes this is what I meant, thx

I do not think this question is a duplicate. Even though this problem could be solved by using lending iterators, it is probably unnecessary. For example, see my next comment.

Here is one way to do it using intermediate structs: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d75a1db2d1de8ecb37ce025ce4c262b9

@cafce25 I interpret the edit as the fact that OP changed their mind, and is okay with a non-consuming iter method. I extended that idea into several iter methods, which might or might not be appropriate. My point is that right now this is not certainly a duplicate, depending on OP's needs.

If your solution would suffice, OP could just use this answer of Chayim to their previous question, in fact that question is where your answer belongs IMHO.

To clarify: is your only problem the nested RefCell, and other than that you are satisfied with my answer to your previous question?

@trueequalsfalse thanks a lot, but I would like to avoid the intermediate object.

Yes @ChayimFriedman, this is the case.

@ChayimFriedman and maybe the confirmation that implementing .into_iter(self) yielding Ref<'_, T> is not possible with the default Iterator, correct? I.e. I would then need a lending iterator.

Yes, that's true. So both of those?

No, I believe iter(&self) is sufficient for my purpose. I just wanted to make sure that I understand it

And a comment on performance would also be great. Can these iterators be expected to be fast (compared to e.g. just iterating over Vec<T>) or will there be a  significant overhead due to all the reference counting?

Also @ChayimFriedman already a BIG thank you, your answers are definitely deepening my understanding of rust.

Another question: are you okay with unsafe code, or with not using the standard Iterator trait but instead internal iteration (having a method .for_each(|item| ...), the main disadvantage is that you cannot have zip()).

Not having zip() would be a problem

And in general I would like to avoid unsafe code, but if it is not possible otherwise it would be ok.

A nested RefCell is a huge problem for this. Essentially, there is no way to do what you want. Getting a single Ref<T> would be unsound (because the outer RefCell can then be mutated, leading to a use-after-free), as will be getting a Ref<Ref<T>>, for reasons explained here.
The only way to do something similar is to have a custom type that will be yielded:
impl<T> Rep<T> {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> RepIter<'_, T> {
        let data = Ref::map(self.0.borrow(), |data| match data {
            RepType::Allocated(data) => &*data.0,
            _ => panic!("unexpected kind of data"),
        });
        RepIter { data, position: 0 }
    }
}

pub struct RepIter<'a, T> {
    data: Ref<'a, RefCell<Rc<Vec<T>>>>,
    position: usize,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for RepIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = RepItem<'a, T>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.position < self.data.borrow().len() {
            let item = RepItem {
                data: Ref::clone(&self.data),
                position: self.position,
            };
            self.position += 1;
            Some(item)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

pub struct RepItem<'a, T> {
    data: Ref<'a, RefCell<Rc<Vec<T>>>>,
    position: usize,
}

impl<T> RepItem<'_, T> {
    pub fn get(&self) -> Ref<'_, T> {
        Ref::map(self.data.borrow(), |data| &data[self.position])
    }
}

A note about performance: this will be much slower than just iterating over a slice, due to all the bookkeeping needed. But this is probably the best you can get. You can improve the performance of collect() by providing size_hint().
